# how to set uilocalnotification firedate for a fixed date?

Tags: iphone

i want to set localnotification say for a program which starts at 6:00 pm.For that i have taken the time in a date variable and i am comparing it with current date from system.

Say setDate is for fixed date i.e 6.00 pm so i have to set firedate such that it shows the notification before 30 mintes the program starts. The examples i have seen in that the firedate is set according to currentdate.

Can someone tell me how can i set firedate according to my fixed date??

Comment: +1 for  your loaylity  from my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then you can handle your local notification in application delegate file when ever you get the notification.
e.g. here is the delegate method which is fired everytime when you get the local notification.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    //Handle the notificaton when the app is running
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);


        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hey Neha" message:@"Sanjay wants to be your friend " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];

        SystemSoundID bell;  
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WhoopFlp" ofType:@"wav"]], &bell);  
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (bell);

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

        i=0;
    }
}
```

So what I am doing here is simply showing the alert and playing a system sound when my local notification occurs.
So now what you want is to navigate to the page in the program where you were when you get the local notification.So simply in this delegate method you need to allocate your view controller and need to push the view controller to that view where you want to be.
That would solve your problem.
Well i had a similar kind of problem what i wanted is to show the notification in the background and in the front end as well, so writing the 2 different methods in my app was not worthful.so i handled it this way in the delegate method which will show the notification in the front end as well.
Good luck to you.

Comment: hey thank u so much and can u tell me how can i vote you i dont know that ......... thanks

Comment: Hey Neha can you see O to the top left of my answer there are 2 up and down arrows you need to press the up arrow and also you need to check the checkmark the right icon used to accpet belo the O.Let me know did you get that....

Answer (score 2):

You fire the local notification this way

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
         if (localNotif == nil)
         return;
         localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date];// Now here you can manage the fire time.
         localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
         // Notification details
         localNotif.alertBody = @"BusBuddy";
         // Set the action button
         localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
         localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
         localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
         // Specify custom data for the notification
         NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"You are near to reach the Bus Stop" forKey:@"someKey"];
         localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
         // Schedule the notification
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
         [localNotif release];
```

This line of code will work for you. you just need to provide the date time for this

```
localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date];
```

And now for formatting your date time you can refer to these links

- [iphonedevelopertips.com](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/category/date-and-time)
- [developer.apple.com, CFDatesAndTimes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDatesAndTimes/CFDatesAndTimes.html)
- [developer.apple.com, DataFormatting](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html)

Comment: hi thanks for this information can u also help me that when we get a reminder message we get a two buttons on that cancel and view tapping on view application starts from my homepage but i want to redirect it to the page where i am having program list with time..... is there any way to do this???

Comment: Well Neha if that answer helped you then you can also vote me up.You did not vote for me.....Still then i answered your second question....

Answer (score 0):

```
localnotification =[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[localnotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[lodatepicker countDownDuration]]];
[localnotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"];
[localnotification setHasAction: YES];
[localnotification setAlertBody:[lotextview text]];
// [localnotification setSoundName:musicString];
localnotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[localnotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localnotification];
```